# What's the difference between MSDN Visual Studio 2012 downloads

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msdn

I have an earlier copy of an MSDN Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with filename `en_visual_studio_ultimate_2012_x86_dvd_920947.iso`
The MSDN site lists that same download as:
`en_visual_studio_ultimate_2012_x86_dvd_2262106.iso`
The two files have different SHA1 hashes. I cannot find anywhere a list of changes or version info between these two files. Are they the same but patched?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the newer installer (though it has not updated the date) fixes the WebDeploy 3.0 certificate warning that occurs on installation of the first iso. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872457